# TCP / IP freezes if I un-listen without client connected to the server

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, listener

I have a working TCP / IP server that can listen to one or many clients, it is working great! It can received and send data from one client.

My problem is whenever I clicked the `listen` button then `un-listen` by clicking again the button my application `freeze`. The only way to free my application from this `freeze` is to connect another client while my system is still in the process of `un-listening`.

The second problem involves receiving data from multiple clients, yes it can listen and allow multiple clients to be connected to the server but it doesn't received all the messages sent by the client, it only receives the message of the first client.

Here's what my system **`look`** like.

[image]

And here's my **`code`**

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Threading 'Imports Threading Namespace
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class Form1


    Dim stream As NetworkStream
    Dim client As TcpClient
    Dim port As Int32
    Dim localAddr As IPAddress = IPAddress.Any
    Dim server As TcpListener
    Dim tcpClientThread As System.Threading.Thread
    Dim PublicIP = String.Empty 'The IP and Port of the Client that connects to port 7700

    Private Sub Tcpclient()
        port = NUD_Tcp_Port.Value
        ' The statement of TCPClient function
        server = Nothing

        ' Buffer for reading data 
        Dim bytes(1024) As Byte
        Try
            server = New TcpListener(localAddr, port) 'Set the TcpListener on port 13000. 
            server.Start() 'Start listening for client requests.

            writeData(Server_IP_Port) 'Outputs the server's ip and port listening

            'Perform a blocking call to accept requests. 
            'You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here. 
            client = server.AcceptTcpClient()
            writeData("Connected: " & Client_IP_Port())

            Dim data As String = Nothing 'The data we received from client, set the default value to nothing
            stream = client.GetStream() 'Get a stream object for reading and writing 

            Dim i As Int32 = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length) 'Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.

            While (i <> 0)
                'Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i)
                writeData("Received: " & data)
                'Process the data sent by the client.
                data = data.ToUpper()
                Dim msg As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)
                i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            End While


        Catch haha As SocketException
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", haha)
        Finally
            'server.Stop()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Function Client_IP_Port() As String 'Gets the IP and port number of clients who connected to our server
        If PublicIP = String.Empty Then
            Try
                ' Get the clients IP address using Client property            
                Dim ipend As Net.IPEndPoint = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint
                If Not ipend Is Nothing Then
                    PublicIP = ipend.Address.ToString & " : " & ipend.Port.ToString
                End If
            Catch ex As System.ObjectDisposedException
                PublicIP = String.Empty
            Catch ex As SocketException
                PublicIP = String.Empty
            End Try
        End If
        Return PublicIP
    End Function

    Function Server_IP_Port() 'Get the IP and port number of server that it listens
        Dim IPListening = IPAddress.Parse(CType(server.LocalEndpoint, IPEndPoint).Address.ToString()).ToString
        Dim PortListening = CType(server.LocalEndpoint, IPEndPoint).Port.ToString()
        If IPListening = "0.0.0.0" Then
            IPListening = "any IP Address"
        End If
        Return "Listening on " & IPListening & " : " & PortListening
    End Function

    Private Sub Tcp_Send(Msg_Send As String)

        Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Msg_Send)
        stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
        writeData("Sent: " & Msg_Send)
    End Sub

    Public Sub StopListen() 'Function to telll to the server to stop listening
        Try
            client.Close()
        Catch err As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(err)
        End Try

        tcpClientThread.Abort()

        server.Stop()
        Btn_Listen.Text = "Listen"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btn_Listen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Listen.Click
        If Btn_Listen.Text = "Listen" Then
            tcpClientThread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Me.Tcpclient)
            tcpClientThread.Start()
            Btn_Listen.Text = "Close"
        Else
            StopListen()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub writeData(ByVal data As Object)
        If InvokeRequired Then
            Invoke(New Action(Of Object)(AddressOf writeData), data)
        Else
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & data)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btn_Send_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Send.Click
        Tcp_Send(TB_Tcp_Send.Text)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why it is freezing in this specific case, but generally speaking you should try to listen asynchronously.  Because regular listening is a blocking instruction.  So maybe it is not really freezing when you click the unlisten, but was frozen (blocking) anyway and you just made it show that it was blocked when you tried to interact with the UI again.

Comment: @WDS, thanks! Can you help me make that code asynchronously? Or, maybe it's a big change on the code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot help with that for a couple reasons, one being that I am too rusty on VB and another that I need to get to sleep very soon.  But it is not too complicated compared to synchronous listening.  I recommend the VB tab in this example to start you in the right direction:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: @WDS, thank you so much. Well at least you help me to be on the right tract.